# Checkbox to select/unselect all series in c3.js

Tags: pandas, c3.js

I have a fairly big amount of data displayed on graphs using c3.js and I was wondering if it was possible to implement a checkbox for each graph with the option to select or unselect all.

I couldn't find anything related on the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for the same?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want the possibility to hide or show all data at once.
In some of my charts I have buttons to show or hide all data

In a basic html/js example:

```
<div id='mychart'></div>
<button onclick="chart.show()">Show All</button>
<button onclick="chart.hide()">Hide All</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = c3.generate(...);
    });
</script>
```